# What is the relation between the blue align-guide-lines and auto-layout in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-autolayout

I have been playing around with auto-layout in Xcode and I noticed that if you don't place your views using the suggested blue guide lines auto layout doesnt behave as you would expect.

Is there any relation between the blue guide lines and auto layout? If yes, can someone explain the relation between the two features?

[image]

Again what I'm trying to understand is how the guide-lines affect the auto layout behavior.

Comment: These lines are simply convenience guides that let you place the views quicker related to superview or other subviews frames and margins. You don't have to use them, configuration of each constraint can be changed after it is added, but it is faster to add constraint with the desired options at once.

Comment: It's what I thought, that they were just a convenience feature but it appears to make auto layout behave differently. I tried applying the same constrains to some views, first I placed them using the guide lines and then I placed them without using guide lines and the result was different, you get better result when you use the guide lines. I'm assuming is because when you use the guide lines you are letting Xcode know about where the nearest view are.

Comment: This blue guidelines simply tells that, this default spacing/distance you should use between any two views. This will appear as suggestion to user for leading, trailing, top, bottom, spacing etc with default or minimum distance to other view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out how the blue guide lines help when working with auto layout (constraints). There is one advantage when placing views using the blue guide lines, it helps XCode know where the nearest neighbors are around the view you are placing.

So, in theory the blue lines are not part of Auto-layout but they help a lot.